# Using setInterval and AJAX to detect a server-side change

Tags: ajax, shopify

I have a server-side "cart" variable that gets updated via an AJAX call when a button is clicked (I'm using Shopify, if it matters, but I feel that this is a general question).  I am using AJAX to reload a `div` once the cart changes.  The problem I encountered was this:

1. I submit the "update cart" AJAX call
2. Immediately after I try to reload the div
3. Depending on the exact timing, maybe 1 out of every 10 times the reload would use the old cart data, since the cart change hadn't registered on the server yet.

I came up with a solution to use `setInterval`, but I think there are some serious problems with this method.  I'll show the code first, then share my concerns.

```
function addToCart(prodid,prodHandle,sizeString){
  var oldSpaces = getNumSpaces(); //gets the number of "free spaces" to display

  //the actual call to update the cart
  push_to_queue(prodid, 1, {}, Shopify.moveAlong);

 //now wait for the number of items to change (ignore the possibility of cart update 
//failure, that's handled elsewhere)
  var timerVar = setInterval(function(){   
    var newSpaces = getNumSpaces();
    if(newSpaces != oldSpaces)
    {
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#toybox").load(" #toybox > *");      
      clearInterval(timerVar);
  });
    }
  },200);
};
```

My concerns are that this feels *extremely* hacky.  I'm running my update function once every 200ms.  Is there a way (in general preferably but in shopify only if need be) to ask the server itself to let me know when something has changed?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a strange question. The server does not change the cart. The client changes the cart. So when you ask for a preferable way to ask the server to let you know when something has changed, the answer will always be, that is never going to happen.

If you want to know when the cart changes, you will always know since you can listen to all cart events client side. Since you are coding up things client side, you need not trouble yourself with server events.

That is how Shopify cart works, and you are asking for advice with that in mind, so I hope this helps you. Polling every 200ms, or N ms or any seconds is a pointless exercise in wasting browser cycles.